# Is the version of Aperture on the Apple Mac App Store identical to boxed version?

Tags: software, apple-aperture, macintosh, pricing

I noticed that the Mac App Store offers Aperture at a significantly reduced price - £44.95 or $79.99 (depending on region).

Does anyone know if there are any differences between this online version and the boxed version I bought last year, apart from the lack of physical media?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The software is the same.**  As you note, you won't have physical media.  In theory this shouldn't be a problem since the App Store will allow you to install it on any of your OS X computers.